# Convert REGEX that works in php to Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I Seem to have a problem working this one out,

I wanting JavaScript to remove any PHP code from a text input before it AJAX send's it to the server now the server will have the removal as well in case some one tries pushing to my AJAX script without using the site however i must be missing something in converting it to JS.

So in php my REGEX is `/\<\?php(.*?)\?\>/gsi`

in JavaScript the `s` modifier does not work.

Comment: What's the function `/s` in PHP?

Comment: @iplus26: It makes `.` match a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, you can't use a `/s` singleline modifier. Instead of it and `.`, use `[\s\S]` as the combination of `\s` (matching a whitespace symbol) and `\S` (matching a non-whitespace symbol) inside a character class makes it match *any* symbol including a newline:

```
/<\?php([\s\S]*?)\?>/gi
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU2jY1/2)

In fact, you can use any reverse shorthand classes inside a character class to make it match *any* symbol: `[\d\D]`, `[\w\W]`, `[\s\S]`. And in some other languages same can be done with `\p` and `\P`: `[\p{L}\P{L}]`, and so on and so forth.

Or, you may use `[^]` that also matches *any character including a newline*:

```
<\?php([^]*?)\?
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU2jY1/3)

Note that `[^]` is only used in JavaScript, and this regex will not be portable, while `[\s\S]` solution is kind of cross-platform (can be used in many regex flavors).

Comment: Thanks what does `\s\S` do then i know `\s` allows White-space so what does the `\S` do?

Comment: The combination of `\s` (a whitespace symbol) and `\S` (a non-whitespace symbol) inside a character class make it match *any* symbol.

Comment: I have added all the explanations to the answer.

Comment: Thanks i was waiting for the timer to mark as answer so it has been done now :)